# Store prop data in local storage in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, callback, trello

I'm working on a react library `react-trello` and trying to save the data to local storage.

My code:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'
 import Board from 'react-trello'
 import './App.css'

class NewCardForm extends Component {
  handleAdd = () => this.props.onAdd({title: this.titleRef.value, description: this.descRef.value, label: this.label.value})
  setTitleRef = (ref) => this.titleRef = ref
  setDescRef = (ref) => this.descRef = ref
  setLabelRef = (ref) => this.label = ref
  render() {
  const {onCancel} = this.props
  return (
   <div style={{background: 'white', borderRadius: 3, border: '1px solid #eee', borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc'}}>
    <div style={{padding: 5, margin: 5}}>
      <div>
        <div style={{marginBottom: 5}}>
          <input type="text" ref={this.setTitleRef} placeholder="User" />
        </div>
        <div style={{marginBottom: 5}}>
          <input type="text" ref={this.setDescRef} placeholder="Task Description" />
        </div>
        <div style={{marginBottom: 5}}>
          <input type="text" ref={this.setLabelRef} placeholder="Date" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
    ) 
  }
}


 function App() {

  const data = {
   lanes: [
   {
    id: 'board1',
    title: 'Incompleted Tasks',
    current: "70", // custom property
    target: "100", // custom property
    label: 'First board here',
    cards: [
      {
        id: 'Card1',
        title: 'Abhishek',
        description: 'Thanks. Please schedule me for an estimate on Monday.'
      },
      {
        id: 'Card2',
        title: 'Rohan',
        description: 'Email received at 1:14pm'
      }
    ]
   },
   {
    id: 'board2',
    title: 'Completed Tasks',
    label: 'Second board here',
    current: "30", // custom property
    target: "100", // custom property
    cards: [
      {
        id: 'Card3',
        title: 'Rachit',
        description: 'You are welcome. Interested in doing business with you again',
       }
       ]
      }
    ]
  }

  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('data');
  console.log('data: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

  return (
   <div className="app">
      <h1>Notion to organize</h1>
    <p>
      Your team’s long term memory, all in one spot.Organize anything, together.
    </p>

    <Board
      onDataChange={(newData) => {console.log(newData)}}
      onCardAdd={(card) => {localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(card));
                        var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('data');
                        console.log(retrievedObject)}}
      style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFEFC'}}
      canAddLanes
      editable
      laneDraggable
      laneStyle={{backgroundColor: '#F9F5F1', marginRight: '50px', paddingTop: '20px'}}
      cardDraggable
      draggable
      data={JSON.parse(retrievedObject)}
      collapsibleLanes
      components={{NewCardForm: NewCardForm}} 
    >
  
      </Board>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

currently I'm rendering `data` to display board. I am calling `onCardAdd` event which triggers whenever data is changed in card. I am successfully able to get data inside card. but how can I save that data to  local storage such that next time I refresh the page the data is there on browser.

you can find the library here.[react-trello](https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello/)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

come to it, you might not need cookie

> What you need is a cookie.
>
> Try using [react-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie) or [react-cookies](https://github.com/bukinoshita/react-cookies) that you find fancy.
>
> if you use `react-cookie` while using class component, you will need
> to wrap your app in `<CookiesProvider/>` and use Higher order
> component `withCookies()` method.

you should try to use `useEffect`, where when you start your app, you should check your `localStorage` first if you have any data i.e. retrieve from that, and if you dont, you just start the new one.

Make sure you dont talk directly to `localStorage` but use a copy of `retrievedObject` by using `useState` so it can be responsive.

[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-butterfly-h5zmj?file=/src/App.js) is not complete work, but it gives you idea

Comment: I tried `cookieprovider` i.e wrapped my board around it but its not working

Comment: can you help. I mean try it on sandbox and check ?

Comment: wait, actually you can still use localStorage, but you need to add useEffect in your App.
let me show you

Comment: That will be great help! Thanks

Comment: have you made the solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React lifecycle componentDidmount and getItem from local storage there, then setState the data, and use it in your component.